# Why didn't the last survivors of krypton go to the phantom zone to live?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

Why didn't the last survivors, the council, and Kal-El's mother go to the phantom zone to at least survive or in a scout ship to find other inhabitant planets during the destruction of Krypton in *Man of Steel*? They had a chance to live like Zod did. We also see Zod need the codex so the unborn child may have the destiny in their life as they are programmed to be. So that explains the council also sent unborn child machine to the phantom zone so why didn't they also go the zone to survive?

Comment: The Phantom zone exists beyond the time and the space. People are inside will not die but they will not be like living a real life. I think their decision depends on their mind, honor,... I mean they wanted to be with their planet, survive with their planet like citizens as they were, not like criminals who are prisoned in the Phantom zone.

Comment: Also the Phantom zone already contains their worse criminals. It follows that if they thought of going there, they probably realized that any of those criminals would seek to kill them, so not a safe bet.

Answer (score 3):

In the Superman Mythos, it is tradition that the Kryptonians don't believe the planet is  doomed, until it's too late. Also, they eliminated their space program centuries, if not millenia before, so scout ships are out.

Naturally, the criminals in the PZ would want to kill them, and try to escape.

Finally, Jor-El and Lara  wanted to leave, but it was impossible to do so-------the whole point of the rocket was for Kal-El to be the sole survivor.